# Kudo shows extra Process

Tags: azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have a triggered web job, hosted in 1 instance App Service Plan.

In Kudo Process, why do I see two processes? See picture.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

​The process labeled as SCM is for running Kudu, the other one is for the web App

- Every Azure Web App includes a “background “service site called [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Full-stopping-a-Web-App). It is useful for capturing memory dumps, looking at deployment logs, viewing configuration parameters and much more.